# Creating Concatenated Tables from Multiple Existing Tables in Excel Without Macros

Tags: excel

can Excel create concatenated tables from multiple input tables?
I have been using python excel writer to automate the creation of product names from master tables. I was wondering if there is any way to do the example bellow
entirely in Excel without using macros or an external tool.

Product Types Master Table

| Product Type Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| HBG | Hand Bag |
| CRBG | Canvage Reusable Bag |

Product Colors Master Table

| Color Code | Color Name |
| --- | --- |
| RD | Red |
| BU | Blue |
| GR | Green |

Desired Output:

| Product | Description |
| --- | --- |
| HBG-RD | Red Hand Bag |
| CRBG-RD | Red Canvage Reusable Bag |
| HBG-BU | Blue Hand Bag |
| CRBG-BU | Blue Canvage Reusable Bag |
| HBG-GR | Green Hand Bag |
| CRBG-GR | Green Canvage Reusable Bag |

Comment: You could do it using `Power Query` (`Get & Transform`) which has been available in Excel since Excel 2010.

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld Please submit as answer so I can give you the credit you deserve :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you can do this using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365.

***Example M Code:***

```
let

//Read in the tables
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Types"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product Type Code", type text}, {"Description", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Colors"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Color Code", type text}, {"Color Name", type text}}),

//Add Custom Column to Types with all the color codes
    #"Add Colors" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Colors", each #"Changed Type2"),
    #"Expanded Colors" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add Colors", "Colors", {"Color Code", "Color Name"}, {"Color Code", "Color Name"}),

//Concatenate code and color
    #"Concat" = Table.FromColumns(
    {List.Transform(List.Zip({#"Expanded Colors"[Product Type Code], #"Expanded Colors"[Color Code]}), each Text.Combine(_,"-"))}
   & {List.Transform(List.Zip({#"Expanded Colors"[Color Name], #"Expanded Colors"[Description]}), each Text.Combine(_," "))},
   type table[Product=text, Description=text])

in
    #"Concat"
```

***Results from your samples***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can us a formula as well:

```vb
=LET(pt,tblProductType, cc,tblColorCode,
cntRowsPt,ROWS(pt),cntRowsCC,ROWS(cc),
MAKEARRAY(cntRowsPt*cntRowsCC,2,LAMBDA(r,c,
  IF(c=1,
     INDEX(pt,INT(ROUNDUP(r/cntRowsCC,0)),1) & "-" & INDEX(cc,MOD(r-1,cntRowsCC)+1,1),
   INDEX(cc,MOD(r-1,cntRowsCC)+1,2) & " " & INDEX(pt,INT(ROUNDUP(r/cntRowsCC,0)),2))
)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative formula-based approach:

```
=HSTACK(
    TOCOL(TOROW(tblProductType[Product Type Code]) & "-" & tblColorCode[Color Code]),
    TOCOL(tblColorCode[Color Name] & " " & TOROW(tblProductType[Description]))
)
```